# Android AudioView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

Is there a library similar to VideoView, but just for plain audio? I need to do something similar looking as the audio view in WhatsApp. I couldn't really find any good library for this, especially to work ok with RecyclerView. I have found some hard solutions with a lot of code, and i'm thinking, it can't really be that no one needed something like this. There are a lot of solutions for video based on ExoPlayer that really elegant, nut not for only audio.

Any hint would be really appreciated

[image]

Comment: android provides nothing of the sort, but that looks like it could be easily created in recycler view

Comment: @tyczj The layout is easy to make, but i'm not really sure about the playback logic. There probably should be just one instance of Media/Exo player, but not sure about the logic of handling all the details.